# A question about the $2\times2$ matrices action on 2-torus.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Given a $2\times2$ matrix $A$ with entries in $\mathbb Z$, it acts on 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb T^2=\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2
\end{equation}
and then leads to a map 
\begin{equation}
A_*\colon H_2(\mathbb T^2)\to H_2(\mathbb T^2)
\end{equation}

I want to know is this map just the scalar multiplication by $\det A$?

Can someone suggest a neat proof?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Very brief idea: $H_2(\Bbb T^2)$ is induced by the degree map on cycles.

Comment: Yes. To my mind it's easier to see the corresponding fact for cohomology $H^2$ (because then you can use the cup product), then apply UCT.